# Uniformly continuous functions and equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

Is stating that a family of functions $\mathscr{F}$ is equicontinuous the same as saying that all $f \in \mathscr{F}$ are uniformly continuous?

Rudin defines a family $\mathscr{F}$ of complex functions $f$ on a set $E$ in metric space $X$ to be eqiucontinuous on $E$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$
whenever $d(x, y)<\delta, x\in E, y\in E, f\in \mathscr{F}$.

Comment: It is not just uniform continuity, but it says that the same $\delta$ works for *all* $f$. If it were just uniform continuity, then each $f$ would have it's own $\delta$ for a fixed $\epsilon$, but here the $\delta$ is the same for all the $f$. So it's a much stronger property, than just uniform continuity of each function .

Comment: That makes sense -- but in the case that each $f$ has its own $\delta$, wouldn't taking the minimum of all of those $\delta$'s give us one for all $f$?

Comment: I am very happy you asked this, because it will clear a major doubt for many people. The point is, we want $\delta > 0$ to hold. Suppose that for $f_1$, the $\delta$ is $1$. For $f_2$, it is $\delta = \frac 12$... for $f_n$, it is $\delta = \frac 1n$. Then, if we have infinitely many $f$, then taking the minimum over all $\delta$ would give us $\delta = 0$, which is a problem. In short  : *The infimum of an infinite set of non-zero elements can be zero*, so one can't necessarily pick the "least" $\delta$ of a bunch of $\delta$s, it may very well happen that there is no such least $\delta$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Func}{\mathscr{F}}$Equicontinuity implies uniform continuity of every member of the family, but is strictly stronger: The family $\Func = (f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ on $[0, 1]$ defined by $f_{n}(x) = x^{n}$ is not equicontinuous, but each member is uniformly continuous.

Intuitively, equicontinuity of a family $\Func$ means that for each $\varepsilon > 0$, you can choose $\delta > 0$ *uniformly over $\Func$*.